# My xpath query isn't finding any results

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a simple xml node, and an equally simple xpath query expression, but it's not working properly. I've tried all sorts of variations on it (//node-name, *[name()='node-name'], current-node-name/node-name), but it's still not finding the correct node!

Here's my xml:

```
<page-reference xmlns="http://something.com">
  <relative-path>something/something</relative-path>
  <base-path>somePath</base-path>
</page-reference>
```

I've tried a few different variations of x-paths. Most of them work if I take out the xmlns attribute of the page-reference tag. For example: `//relative-path, /page-reference/relative-path, relative-path, page-reference/relative-path`, but none of them work with the xmlns attribute.

Any ideas what could be causing this? I thought that it's the double slash after the http in the value, but I have no idea why that would cause an issue, and it also does not seem to be the case.

Comment: What language are you using to parse/invoke the XPath on the XML?

Comment: @Shah I'm using Javascript for my real application. I'm also doing testing using http://www.xpathtester.com/test to test my xpath with the xml in my node. They are both not retrieving any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Or, alternatively, you could use**:

```
//*[name()='relative-path']
```

Answer (score 2):

The `xmlns` attribute provides a namespace for the element, meaning it is not just a normal "page-reference" or "relative-path" element, so it cannot be accessed as such. Different languages have different ways of indicating the namespace, from indicating the default for your XPath queries to using prefixes.

For JavaScript, you can use a namespace resolver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver (if you want to specify prefixes--useful when there are different namespaces used within the document) and/or to rely on a default namespace within XPath expressions (though you need to use some--ANY--prefix): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_default_namespace_for_XML_documents

```
var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<page-reference xmlns="http://something.com">'+
  '<relative-path>something/something</relative-path>'+
  '<base-path>somePath</base-path>'+
'</page-reference>', 'text/xml');

function resolver() {
    return 'http://something.com';
}
var refs = xml.evaluate('//x:page-reference', xml, resolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
alert(refs.snapshotItem(0).nodeName) // 'page-reference'
```

You'll need a shim for IE support. (A quick search turned up http://sourceforge.net/projects/js-xpath/files/js-xpath/ )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure that the xmlns would always be the same for the xml I'm using (I have no control over it at all), so I don't know that this would work for me.

Answer (score 1):

XPath is not aware of a "default" XML namespace (xmlns). As a result, you'll need to prefix all of your nodes in your XPath expressions with the page-reference tag's namespace.

**XML:**

```
<page-reference xmlns:s="http://something.com">
  <relative-path>something/something</relative-path>
  <base-path>somePath</base-path>
</page-reference>
```

**XPath:**

```
//s:relative-path
```

Comment: That sounds like it should work, but I don't have any control over the xml that's coming in. It comes in without a name for the namespace. Is there any way I can access it anyhow?

Comment: Use a default namespace resolver--as per my comment below (you could also use with a prefix, as the prefix doesn't need to be in the document as longer as the resolver handles it)

Comment: @chama, can you share your JavaScript in the question? That would help us determine how you need to add the default namespace to the parser within the context of your code.

Comment: @hall.stephenk I would, but right now, I'm not really using any code. I'm just using an xpath tester to with the xml I listed. I said which tester I'm using in my comment in response to Shah

Comment: @chama, that's fair enough. I think you'll need to actually move it into code to implement the solution Brett Zamir mentions (and I'm suggesting as well) since you can't manipulate the XML. The test site you're using is the same one I used and it gives a link related to default namespaces and XPath: http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html#Conclusion